# dart.io is not supported for web, and universal.io's File doesn't work when assigning arguments

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage, flutter-web, dart-io

I am making a website and would like files to be uploaded to Firebase Cloud Storage. The issue is, `FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child().putfile()` takes in a File, which is from `dart.io` (apparently not supported for web). I tried using `universal.io`, but I get a type mismatch error.

To reproduce, just make a web project with cloud storage and try to `putfile`.

Any solutions would be appreciated

Comment: did you try using `dart:html`

Answer (score 0):

For flutter web you can use putdata instead of putfile

```
putData(
            file.bytes,
            SettableMetadata(contentType: 'image/${file.extension}'),
          );
```

Comment: so if i wanted to put the file text.txt, how would i do that?

Comment: In content type add text/plain

Comment: what should i do for file?

Comment: You don't need file. Putdata takes list of int. And content type takes a string.

Comment: so whats file.bytes for?

Comment: I assume you are using file picker to pick files. In its result read the bytes and save it in a variable. Use this list of int